# CS50 Pset6 error 405 keeps on printing server.c

Tags: c, cs50

So my code, no matter what, returns error 405 (once the test that only two spaces are in the request-line is passed). Which makes me believe I have made an error in creating a code to determine that "GET" is in fact the first word. This is all my code leading up to the "check" that the method type is "GET" or any capitalization thereof.

```
   int s;
   s=0;
   int i=0;
    for(int q=0; q<strlen(line); q++)
    {
        if(line[q] == ' ')
            s++;
    }
    if(s!=2)
    {
       error(400);
       return false;
    }
if((line[i] != 'g' || line[i] != 'G') || (line[i+1] != 'e' || line[i+1] != 'E') || (line[i+2] != 't' || line[i+2] != 'T')||
    (line[i+3] != ' '  ))
        {
            error(405);
            return false;
        }
```

Any reason this would always return false? I have `int i` initialized to `0`.

Comment: Have you heard about `string.h` functions?

Comment: if line[i] is equal to g, then it is NOT equal to G, hence you return false.

Comment: `if !strncasecmp(line, "get", 3) ...` is so much easier to type, and also to understand, apparently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any reason this would always return false?

**Reason :**

- consider the `if` statement as :

  ```
  if(expression_1 || expression_2 || expression_3 || expression_4)
  //where
  //expression_1 is (line[i] != 'g' || line[i] != 'G')
  //expression_2 is (line[i] != 'e' || line[i] != 'E')
  //expression_3 is (line[i] != 't' || line[i] != 'T')
  //expression_4 is (line[i] != ' ')
  ```
- let's consider `line` as `GET`
- Now, `expression_1` is **always** evaluated to be `true` even though `line[i] == G`  because `line[i] != 'g'` is `true`. Therefore, `(line[i] != 'g' || line[i] != 'G')` is `true` as `true || false == true`
- Now further expressions are not evaluated as `||` is a lazy operator and it stops evaluation on first `true` occurrence as `true || anything == true`
- Thus, `if` block is always entered and `false` is always returned.

---

**Solution :**

- Change the `if` in your code :

  ```
  if((line[i] != 'g' || line[i] != 'G') || (line[i+1] != 'e' || line[i+1] != 'E') || (line[i+2] != 't' || line[i+2] != 'T') || (line[i+3] != ' '  ))
  ```
- To the following :

  ```
  if((line[i] != 'g' && line[i] != 'G') || (line[i+1] != 'e' && line[i+1] != 'E') || (line[i+2] != 't' && line[i+2] != 'T') || (line[i+3] != ' '  ))
  ```
- Here `line[i] != 'g' && line[i] != 'G'` gets evaluated to `false` as `true && false == false` and further expressions are checked till a `true` is encountered.
- If no `true` is encountered then `if()` block is not entered

---

Further,

- As *[@twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg)* has suggested in the [*comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512587/cs50-pset6-error-405-keeps-on-printing-server-c#comment64422986_38512587), it'd be much readable and understandable if you use your `if` statement as `if( !strncasecmp(line, "get ", 3) )` by including the `strings.h` header file
- Know more about `strncasemp()` function here : *[click](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/nonstandard/strncasecmp)*

Answer (score 0):

That comparison makes the code much harder to read. Use the function `strncasecmp()` (in either `string.h` or `strings.h`) instead:

```
if (strncasecmp(line, "get ", strlen("get ")) != 0) {
    // ...
}
```

This will fix the logic error in that line -- your current comparison will always evaluate `true`. I would also suggest enabling more compiler warnings, as this is something that any compiler should catch.